# Propagate traceId from Microservice and Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Sleuth to generate logs that gets me traceId and spanId. I want to propagate these to Kafka topic, maybe in the header, and from there to another microservice that will consume from the header through that topic, so that traces are consistent for the same payload. Are there any properties I can configure to make this work?

Comment: I wonder why Spring Cloud Sleuth instrumentation for Apache Kafka doesn't work for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-integration

Comment: Ill try to modify the questions after some R&D.

Comment: If I pass a custom header X-B3-TraceId  along with the payload (producer side), Im expecting Sleuth to pick it up from the header instead of generating its own (consumer side). This worked for http request when passing through a header. Is there a way to do for Kafka as well?

Comment: That's probably something what have to be done on the consumer side. Perhaps some Brave configuration to propagate such a header properly from the consumed record.

Comment: With non-reactive KafkaTemplate, Sleuth automatically sends b3 header and consumer is picking up same traceid. With ReactivceKafkaProducerTemplate, no headers are sent and consumer is generating its own traceid.

Comment: Do you follow that documentation about instrumenting Reactor Kafka: `KafkaReceiver.create(tracingKafkaConsumerFactory, kafkaReceiverOptions)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250095/discussion-between-sudip-subedi-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: No, I don't do chats over here. Sorry, just continue to add comments over here.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, just added the TracingKafkaProducerFactory in the producer side and able to generate the b3 header. Is there a way to replace this auto generated header? I tried adding a custom header with b3 as key but it is just getting added to the list. Now the header has two b3 but only autogenerated one is propagated to cosnumer side.

Comment: How about to continue using your custom one on the producer, but instrument a consumer with respective `TracingKafkaConsumerFactory`?